# Согласование местоимения с глаголом

Tags: согласование

Очень интересно узнать. Почему местоимение «Те» употребляется с глаголом «любил» в единственном числе. Текст на фото.

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/AgbRQ.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

**Те, кто любил друг друга в этой жизни, непременно встретятся после.**

1) Я считаю, что придаточное  предложение составлено **не  совсем корректно**. Мы говорим: они **любили ДРУГ ДРУГА.** Здесь обязательное мн. число.,  и его желательно сохранить и в придаточном предложении:

Те, кто **любили друг друга** в этой жизни, непременно встретятся после.

2) Правило Рзенталя допускает разное число для сказуемого в главном и придаточном предложении при наличии местоимения ***кто***, но в нашем случае мн. число в придаточном предложении **мы уже выбрали.**

Правило Розенталя  [http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/64.htm#з_05](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/64.htm#%D0%B7_05)

2. При подлежащем – относительном местоимении **кто** (в функции союзного слова в придаточном предложении) сказуемое может стоять **как в форме единственного, так и в форме множественного числа, например:**

а)      **Все, кто не потерял** еще головы, **были** против (Сергеев-Ценский);

б)       В полку **служат** теперь **те, кто** десять лет назад **были** пионерами, **бегали** в школу, **играли** в снежки (Б. Полевой).

Answer (score 1):

Основной (*нейтральной*) формой глагола при местоимении **кто** является форма *единственного* числа. При необходимости *подчеркнуть* множественность производителей действия в сложноподчинённом предложении допускается множественное число, но при соблюдении дополнительных условий. Из Розенталя:

> *При подлежащем – относительном местоимении **кто** (в функции союзного
>   слова в придаточном предложении) сказуемое может стоять как в форме
>   единственного, так и в форме множественного числа. Форма
>   множественного числа, возможная **при условии**, что в главном предложении
>   соотносительное слово и сказуемое тоже стоят во множественном числе,
>   подчеркивает множественность производителей действия. Конструкции типа
>   **первые, кто пришли; последние, кто записались** (с субстантивированным
>   прилагательным-подлежащим в главном предложении) являются
>   **разговорными**.*

http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/64.htm

Что касается исходного примера,

> Те, кто **любил** друг друга в этой жизни, непременно встретятся после.

то формально условия, допускающие множественное число, выполняются (по Розенталю, во множественном числе сказуемое *встретятся* и соотносительное слово *те*). Кроме того, как справедливо заметила *Jasmin*, в нашем случае едва ли можно приписать единственное число местоимению **кто**, напр. условно заменив его на "каждый из которых" (нельзя одному человеку "любить друг друга", только "другого"), поэтому исходный вариант, хотя и встречается (даже в учебнике "Школьный словарь антонимов", Г. П. Никольская, 2009 есть цитата из речи персонажа у С. Бабаевского: "... тем, кто любил друг друга в молодости, нельзя встречаться в старости"), является как минимум *спорным*. Вариант же с множественным числом

> Те, кто любил**и** друг друга в этой жизни, непременно встретятся после.

трудно подвергнуть критике, хотя из стилистических соображений (подальше от риторического уклона программы "Время" на множественное число после "кто") я предпочёл бы "**Любившие друг друга...**".